# How to categorize wordpress custom post for upcoming event and past event

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post 'webinar' and now i want to show upcoming webinar on a separate section and past webinar on separate section by using wordpress categories.

here is my custom post type:-

```
// webinar post type
    $labels = array(
            'name'               => _x( 'Webinars', 'post type general name', 'impactqa' ),
            'singular_name'      => _x( 'Webinar', 'post type singular name', 'impactqa' ),
            'menu_name'          => _x( 'Webinars', 'admin menu', 'impactqa' ),
            'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Webinar', 'add new on admin bar', 'impactqa' ),
            'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Webinar', 'impactqa' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Webinar', 'impactqa' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'New Webinar', 'impactqa' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Webinar', 'impactqa' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Webinar', 'impactqa' ),
            'all_items'          => __( 'All Webinars', 'impactqa' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search Webinars', 'impactqa' ),
            'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Webinars:', 'impactqa' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No Webinars found.', 'impactqa' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Webinars found in Trash.', 'impactqa' )
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels'             => $labels,
                    'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'impactqa' ),
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'webinar', 'with_front' => false ),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'menu_position'      => null,
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' )
        );

        register_post_type( 'webinar', $args );

        $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Webinar Categories', 'impactqa' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Webinar Category', 'impactqa' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Webinar Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Webinar Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Webinar Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Webinar Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Webinar Category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Webinar Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Webinar Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Webinar Category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Webinar Categories' ),
    );
         $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'rewrite'   => array( 'with_front'    => false ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'webinar_category', 'webinar', $args );
```

and here is my template code:-

```
 <section class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="pb-30">Upcoming Webinars</h2>
                <hr class="serprate-line" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, grey, transparent);">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'post_type' => 'webinar', 
                    'post_status' => 'publish', 
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    
                    )
                );
        if ($query->have_posts()) :
                while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                    $date_posted = get_field('date_posted');
                    $date_posted = strtotime($date_posted); 
                    $date_current = date('Ymd'); // the date format should be same as the date format on $date_posted
                    $date_current = strtotime($date_current);
                    if ($date_posted >= $date_current) : // compare date
                    $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full');?>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                        <div class="webinar-wrapper">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>"></a>
                            <div class="webinar-title">
                                <h5><a href=""><?php echo get_field('webinar_heading'); ?></a></h5>
                            </div>
                            <span class="pDate"><?php echo get_the_date('d M, Y'); ?></span> <!-- <span class="pipe">|</span> -->
                            <!-- <span class="pTime"><?php echo get_the_time(); ?></span> -->
                            <!-- <span class="minRead">
                                <?php
                                $words = str_word_count(get_the_content());
                                $perMinutes = 200;
                                $minutes = ceil($words/$perMinutes);
                                echo $minutes.' MIN';
                                ?>
                            </span> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
    <?php
endif;
     endwhile;
            endif;  ?>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<section class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="pb-30">Past Webinars</h2>
                <hr class="serprate-line" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, grey, transparent);">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'post_type' => 'webinar', 
                    'post_status' => 'publish', 
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    
                    )
                );
        if ($query->have_posts()) :
                while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                    $date_posted = get_field('date_posted');
                    echo $date_posted;
                    $date_posted = strtotime($date_posted); 
                    $date_current = date('Ymd'); // the date format should be same as the date format on $date_posted
                    $date_current = strtotime($date_current);
                    if ($date_posted < $date_current) : // compare date
                    $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full');?>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                        <div class="webinar-wrapper">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>"></a>
                            <div class="webinar-title">
                                <h5><a href=""><?php echo get_field('webinar_heading'); ?></a></h5>
                            </div>
                            <span class="pDate"><?php echo get_the_date('d M, Y'); ?></span> <!-- <span class="pipe">|</span> -->
                            <!-- <span class="pTime"><?php echo get_the_time(); ?></span> -->
                            <!-- <span class="minRead">
                                <?php
                                $words = str_word_count(get_the_content());
                                $perMinutes = 200;
                                $minutes = ceil($words/$perMinutes);
                                echo $minutes.' MIN';
                                ?>
                            </span> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
    <?php
endif;
     endwhile;
            endif;  ?>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Issue- when i puting some events in backend then its showing on past event section and upcoming section is blank.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Post your code/attempt, example data, expected result from that data and what currently happens (we need details, incl. full error messages, if any.) Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that was recommended to you when you registered.

Comment: Please do the [appropriate amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). We're here to help you fix specific issues you might get stuck on, but we do expect you to have at least done some attempts yourself first. The question is too unfocused at the moment.

Comment: ok i just added my code there